# FILE * сохраняет числа в формате \00\0010 вместо 10

Tags: c++, файлы

Необходимо записывать строки в файл.
Использовать можно только эти библиотеки:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Решил использовать `FILE *`, при этом столкнулся с рядом проблем.
Нужно, чтобы строки содержали текст и переменные. 
Записать все одной командой у меня не получается. 
Сохранить переменную тоже, я попытался сохранить десять чисел 10 в столбик, сохранилось так:

> 10
>   \00\0010
>   \00\0010
>   \00\0010
>   \00\0010
>   \00\0010
>   \00\0010
>   \00\0010
>   \00\0010
>   \00\0010
>   \00\00

Код написал такой:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 FILE *f; 
 int dat=1;
 int n=10;
 char str[5]="";
 f=fopen("/home/user/lol.txt","wt");
 for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
 { dat = 10;
   sprintf(str,"%d\n",dat);
   str[5]=dat;
   fwrite(&str,sizeof(str),1,f);
}
fclose(f);
}
```

Я понимаю, что проблема в кодировке, но не понимаю как исправить. Почитал про Unicode. Начал в общих чертах представлять в чем проблема, но как её решить - не осилил. Если бы все числа были всегда одинаковыми, то можно было бы подобрать размер `char`, так чтобы этих нулей не появлялось, но числа должны быть разными.

Если бы можно было использовать другие библиотеки, то конечное решение всей задачки должно было бы выглядеть как-то так (текст и переменные, которые должны быть в файле представлены упрощенно, так как получаются отдельно):

```
//Создание файла

stringstream slol;
stringstream splol;

slol << "/home/user/lol.txt";
splol << "/home/user/PLol.txt";
ofstream l(slol.str().c_str());
ofstream p(splol.str().c_str());


//Цикл заполняет файл
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
string lol="Text";
l << lol << i << endl;

string plol="PText";
p << plol << i << endl;
}
l.close();
p.close();
return 0;
```

Но у меня не получается продвинуться даже немного из-за неправильного сохранения в файл.

Comment: Если вы пишете на C++, почему вдруг `FILE*` и `fwrite`?

Comment: @Abyx: Этот вопрос — хорошая иллюстрация того, почему `void*` — плохо.

Comment: Зачем Вы пишите `str[5] = dat`? Почему решили использовать `fwrite()` вместо `fputs()` (или просто `fprintf()`)? И как Вы себе представляете, что возвращает `sizeof(str)`? После ответа (прежде всего самому себе) на эти вопросы процесс обучения должен пойти уже легче.

Comment: «Использовать можно только эти библиотеки» — почему? А не лабораторную работу ли вы нам тут предлагаете? (Если да, почему бы вам не спросить у преподавателя?)

Comment: Обо всем по порядку:
Использовал справочник программиста Шилда С/С++ третье издание главу 6. 
Почему void* — плохо видимо пойму, когда все заработает).
Вопросы про fwrite() вместо fputs() и прочее рассмотрю, спасибо.
Использовать эти библиотеки по некоторым техническим проблемам, если бы это была лабораторная, то все было светло и безоблачно))

Comment: @Alexandr, прочтите для начала K&R (только внимательно, вдумчиво, скажем за недельку, пробуя на компе прилагаемые примеры), imho все сразу встанет на свои места.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените `sprintf(str,"%d\n",dat)` на `fprintf(f,"%d\n",dat)` и удалите две последние строчки в цикле

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло))

Comment: @Alexandr, Например, `fprintf(f, "Число = %d\n", dat)` или `fprintf(f, "%s = %d\n", str, dat)`

Comment: Хотел переформулировать вопрос, но вы меня опередили и ответили сразу на все, спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

`str[5]=dat;` выход за границы массива. Отсчет в С/C++ с нуля.